# Select max value in one column plus other columns in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012, max

I came across a database table structured like so: every time a user logs in, a new record is added to the database with their username, device, unix timestamp of their login, and 10 other columns of things. For each user, I want to select their most recent login. So I do this:

```
with query1 as (
    select 
        user,
        MAX(last_login)
    from 
        users_table 
    group by 
        user
)
```

As a check, every user is only associated with one row, their latest login:

```
select count(distinct user) from query1  == select count(user) from query1
```

Here lies the issue.  I want to add another column to the select so I add to `group by` too ...

```
with query1 as (
    select 
        user,
        device,  
        MAX(last_login)
    from 
        users_table 
    group by 
        user,
        device
)
```

then the lengths are not equal. For the reason I'm asking this, some users are associated with a single row and some users are associated with multiple rows.

```
select count(distinct user) from query1  != select user from query1
```

Is there something I'm not considering since I want to select the max value of 1 column, but get the entire row as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think "aggregation".  Think "filtering".  Then:

```
select u.*
from users_table u
where u.last_login = (select max(u2.last_login)
                      from users_table u2
                      where u2.user = u.uer
                     );
```

If you want to guarantee one row per user, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*
             row_number() over (partition by user order by last_login desc) as seqnum
      from users_table u
     ) u
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: if I'm doing a where clause on last login, what if two users last login is the same exact time?

Comment: @e1v1s . . . The most recent login is *per user*.